# Selenium WebDriver throws NoSuchElement Exception, then finds elements when I hit continue

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

In the following code

```
using System;
using System.Security.Policy;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace StackOverflowTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("log in")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("google-login")).Click();
            Int16 myInt = 2; //breakpoint goes here.
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Selenium is throwing a 'NoSuchElement' Exception. Then when I hit continue, it clicks the element it supposedly cannot find. Can someone explain to my why this is happening/what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably take some time for the element to load. You can use explicit wait with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) to wait for the element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText("log in"))).Click();
```

Or set implicit wait

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: I figured this out right before you posted it. But I was using Thread.Sleep(25000). Is the WebDriverWait the prefered method of telling selenium to wait? Or would Thread.Sleep work?

Comment: I know this wouldn't be considered a 'race condition'. What would the definition of this be when your application is acting faster than your responding actor can?

Comment: @CryptoJones `Thread.Sleep(25000)` will stop the script for 25 seconds no meter what. `WebDriverWait` with the same time will wait **up** to 25 seconds for the element to meet the condition. If the condition is met after 2 seconds the script will continue after 2 seconds.

Comment: It actually is race condition. The code you use is looking for the element the html "produce" before it exist. That's what `WebDriverWait` was created for.